# Get music on iPod Touch iOS 6.1.3

Tags: 12.04, sync, rhythmbox, ipod, ios

I just got my sister to use Ubuntu, but now I have a really big problem, I promised her that syncing music would work with only drag and drop with Rhythmbox, because that is how I do with my iPod Nano which is old and stuff, but her iPod Touch uses the newest release of iOS and as I have been reading Apple does what ever they can so syncing your iPod only works with iTunes. Now syncing her iPod doesn't work.

Has anyone got an iPod touch to work with Ubuntu? any other software than Rhythmbox would also be fine or even some ugly and long way through the terminal would also be fine.
I am willing to do anything to stop her to use Windows again.

Comment: Note that with each iOS update, it sometimes stops working with the tools in Ubuntu which can work with it.

Answer (score -1):

Banshee player would be a better option because the user interface for handling music players is similar to Itunes. It probable will be the most user friendliest music app I've seen.